# calling another member function from __init__ in python

Tags: python

I wanted to call class member functions to initialize the class members completely in **init**. items_left and rat_initialize are the member functions I am using to initialize all the members of the class instance correctly. Is it alright to do so?

```
class Maze:
    """ A 2D maze. """
    # Write your Maze methods here.
    def __init__(self,maze,rat_1,rat_2):
        self.maze = maze
        self.rat_1 = rat_1
        self.rat_2 = rat_2
        self.num_sprouts_left = 0
        self.items_left(maze)
        self.rat_initialize(maze,rat_1,rat_2)
```

Comment: One of the advantages of python is that you can try and run code easily.  You should run it and see if it works.  Also, since maze, rat_1 and rat_2 are assigned as instance variables, it's not necessary to pass them to self.rat_initialize().

Comment: @monkut: There is, of course, the possibility of undefined behavior where it *appears* to work but is subtly very wrong. Fortunately, Python does not have many of these cases, but you cannot safely assume that without knowing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can do it. When `__init__` is called, the object is already instantiated by this point all the methods are available.

Actual object instantitation takes place in `__new__` and `__init__` is only called after it. You have accesss to other functions from inside `__init__`.